# GRBD Swift Sqlite

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite, grdb

I'm using GRDB library for Swift Sqlite.

I create a class for connection:

import GRDB

var dbQueue: DatabaseQueue!

func setupDatabase() {

```
var config = Configuration()
config.readonly = true
config.foreignKeysEnabled = true
config.trace = { print($0)}



let databasePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("mydb", ofType: "sqlite")!

dbQueue = try! DatabaseQueue(path: databasePath, configuration:  config)
```

}

I call the class in the method:

```
func trovaCitta(luogoNascita: String)->CittaVO{

    let citta:CittaVO = CittaVO()


    dbQueue.inDatabase { db in

        for row in Row.fetch(db, "SELECT * FROM comune where cod_catastale='" + luogoNascita + "'") {
            citta.codIstat = row.value(named: "cod_istat")
            citta.nome = row.value(named: "nome")

                    citta.codProvincia = row.value(named: "cod_provincia")
                    citta.codValidita = row.value(named: "cod_validita")
                    citta.codCap = row.value(named: "cod_cap")
                    citta.codCatastale = row.value(named: "cod_catastale")
          //  print(citta)
        }

    }

    return citta
}
```

The app returns: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

0x1009f8764 <+36>:  mov    x4, x5
    0x1009f8768 <+40>:  bl     0x100a3add0               ; function signature specialization  of Swift.(_fatalErrorMessage (Swift.StaticString, Swift.StaticString, Swift.StaticString, Swift.UInt) -> ()).(closure #2)

someone can give me suggestions?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

I've had better luck with the SQLite.swift framework, instead of GRDB.

Comment: The problem was not inside GRDB, the problem was inside his application code. The full story is here: https://github.com/groue/GRDB.swift/issues/26.

Comment: You should have a look at GRDB, adamek.